# How to correctly import an Android library with JNI code?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

### Background

I've made a tiny SDK for bitmap handling using JNI (link [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations)).

It has only 2 projects : a sample project (demonstrates usage of the SDK), and the SDK itself .

The SDK project is an Android project, and it includes some C/C++ code within it.

### The problem

For some reason, even though when I've created the project , everything went fine, now that I try to get the library project and import it to Eclipse, and then I open the CPP file I've made, I see plenty of errors on it, as such:

[image]

### The question

Why does it occur? How do I import the project correctly? Can I help whoever is using this to be able to import it nicely?

I've tried to create a totally new project with JNI and just copied (carefully) the files from my library, and it compiled fine, but that's not a nice way to import a project...

Comment: I had this very problem too. Does your Eclipse come with the Eclipse CDT plugin installed?

Comment: @dextor no, but when you install the ADT&SDK of Android, it is being installed anyway. maybe i made a single more step for it to support it, but that's it.

Comment: I just tried to import your project in a clean Eclipse workspace (Import -> Existing project into workspace). I do not see any error, except for the fact that you didn't include a `res` folder (even an empty one), which makes the `aapt` tool pretty angry. Still, no errors. Using ADT for OSX.

Comment: @dextor please try to open the cpp file inside the "jni" folder.

Comment: Yup, I already did before you asked about it. I even edited and tried the auto-complete function. All working as expected.

Comment: @dextor but how could it be that i have errors and you don't? do you have the most recent ADT & SDK ? they've made a new version this week...

Comment: I am running the `Android SDK Tools 22.3`. I've checked, and you are right, there is an update which bumps to the 22.6 version. I'm also updating to the `API 19 SDK rev 3`; by the way, I'm using `NDK r9b`. The problem you are facing may be related to the CDT plugin, or to the OS version of the SDK/NDK.

Comment: Well I'm using NDK r9c , and I use 22.6 for the SDK &ADT ... it doesn't make sense. and you said all you had to do is to import the project? nothing more than this? It seems there is already NDK 49d. I will now download it and see if it helps.

Comment: I can confirm that. I just updated everything I could. Again, aside from the missing res/ folder (which you should definitely create), everything compiles perfectly and the CPP file is not screwed up. Autocomplete works.

Comment: Are you using Linux? I am thinking of a platform-specific ADT bug..

Comment: @dextor currently I'm using Windows 8.1 pro (64 bit).

Comment: @dextor even after updating to NDK 49d it didn't help.

Comment: Have you defined NDKROOT environment variable within Eclipse IDE? If not open Eclispe menu Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment, press Add button and set variable name to NDKROOT and value to Android NDK root path i.e. absolute path to android-ndk-r9d folder.

Comment: Forgot to mention one more point in my previous comment, after adding environment variable restart the Eclipse.

Comment: @ManishMulimani Why would you want to put this? There is already a setting for the "NDK location" on "Android"->"NDK" ... Are you sure this will help? have you tried it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This eclipse error happens often , and your solution (starting a empty project then adding the files) is the fastest work-around, and we all use it when it comes to this.
Another solution would be to remove the c nature and Android nature and add again these natures to the project (often times this works as well).

When a new project is created, Eclipse will add it's natures and it's tool chains. If you import an old project, these toolchains / natures might be badly imported.

For a project containing c and c++ , you will need to have cnature and ccnature defined in your ".project" file. For android you need Android Nature.
For compiling android, you will need to have com.android.gcc as the toolchain defined in your .cproject file.

Depending on the version of ADT / CDT / Eclipse , the value from the toolchains in .cproject differs, hence they aren't easy to import from machine to machine.

My guess is you have your storm of errors because the .cproject file was generated wrongfully .

EDIT

After Android Developer's further research, a faster way to bypass Eclipse's limitation caused by how native nature is added to a project can be done in the following steps:

1. delete from the ".project" file the "cnature" and "ccnature"

   ```
   <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>
   <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>
   ```
2. delete the ".cproject" file from eclipse workspace
3. remove all generated files and folders : libs, obj, gen and bin
4. Re-add the native support for android via the "android tools" context menu

Thank you android developer.

Comment: Is there an easier fix for this? my solution isn't as easy as it seems, since you need to carefully delete everything and copy all files from the original project, and use the new library project ...

Comment: Try deleting the .cproject and  the cnature and ccnature from inside the.project file, then choose "convert to c/c++ project" to force recreation of the files. (Make a backup first ofc :) ).

Comment: Have you checked this solution? did you clone the library project I've made and did all of this?

Comment: No, I haven't (sorry, but I'm not at the correct place for this ). I just stated where the problem might come from and how we usually solve it when we bump into. This problem we had not only on Android jni , but also on strictly C / C++ projects.

Comment: ok, i've tried what you offered. it didn't work since there is no "convert to c/C++ project". however, I've found another way: 1. delete the stuff you written. 2. delete the folders "libs","gen","bin",obj". 3. choose "add native support..." via the "android tools" context menu, and it does the whole job . Then you just need to choose the exact code file name for C/C++ . 4. compile and run. This really worked. it's not so nice, but it's better than messing with too many files (in case you have many).

Comment: Ah, yes, add native support is for android :). "convert to c/c++" is when you have only CDT installed. I'm glad it helped :). Basically you "refreshed" the natures of the project .

Comment: if you add the steps I've written (write "EDIT: there is a workaround..." or something like that), I will tick this as the answer, since I don't think there is another way for now.

Comment: You should have written a comment to notify me you've edited the answer. anyway, I've ticked your answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: awsome. thanks for this great help, i have the same problem , may be this will work for me , gen folder is the generated folder generate itself on app import ,,