# Unresolved inclusion issue in NDK android

Tags: android

Unresolved inclusion issue always. I have make R&D over  internet and overflow. But my use case is different.
Once i make any project and path and symbol and all settings done. It's works fine without any warning and error.But if i copy the source code of project to some other place and then import into other work space, with same settings and tool chain path then lot of warnings and error's comes. like>

Unresolved inclusion.
Type can not be resolved
oblect can not be resolved,

How to get rid of this, please help..

Comment: copy the source code of project to some other place means are you copying to a diff place of the same system or a different system?

Comment: same system. and import that source code to other work space creates a problem.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263253/how-to-correctly-import-an-android-library-with-jni-code/22956790#22956790  .